# approximating delta distribution

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I need some clarification for this. 
I know that we can approximate delta distribution by taking $f \in L^1$ by taking $f_j=j^n f(jx)$ when $\int f =c$ for some constant $c$. That`s o.k., but how can we do that when $\int f=0$ ? can anyone please explain this to me?

Thanks

Comment: can you pleas explain more?

Comment: is it clear ? can you adapt it to $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ ?

Comment: I think I understand now, but to be sure I`ll leave it now then come back to it maybe tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> When $f \in L^1$ then $k f(kx) \to F(+\infty)\delta(x)$ in the sense of distributions, where $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy$.

With $\varphi \in C^1$ and compactly supported then $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty k f(kx) \varphi(x) dx = -\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  F(kx) \varphi'(x) dx \\= -\int_0^\infty F(+\infty) \varphi'(x) dx = \varphi(0) F(+\infty)$$